# How to convert Haar cascade xml file to tracking.js format?

Tags: javascript, xml, opencv, converters, tracking.js

I have created a Harcascade xml (new format) in openCV, and now i want to convert this xml to tracking.js

> I have also tried using
>   https://github.com/cirocosta/gulp-converter-tjs but no luck.

Any ideas on how to use my xml to integrate with tracking js ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: As far as I know, there is no better choice than gulp-converter-js, currently.

Comment: might this package can help you without gulp dependencies - https://www.npmjs.com/package/haar2tjs